# Running Dusk with Laravel in Virtual Machine (Homestead) encountering problems with port 3306 and 33060 depending on tests

Tags: laravel, homestead, laravel-dusk

I have a Laravel project setup with Vagrant/Homestead and now want to start doing some Dusk tests.
When I just run a test to see if the homepage shows up (has a certain element) all is fine.

However when I try to add a second test that actually creates a user and signs in, then problems arise. It can't connect to the DB through port 3306 defined in my .env (or .env.dusk.local) file.

The thing is with Homestead there is this Virtual Machine running and when connecting from my host machine to my SQL DB I also have to add an extra "0" to the DB port. So 3306 becomes 33060. So for a minute I tried changing the DB port in .env.dusk.local to 33060 which then runs the test fine but no longer the homepage test.

So far I've been looking into this solution thinking it's related to my setup/problem but it hasn't brought me any further: [OverrideDbPort](https://www.thomasedwards.co.uk/tutorials/installing-chromedriver-on-macos/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Homestead uses port 3306 inside the virtual machine, and exposes this same port over 33060 on your local machine (when connecting via `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`).

Instead, if you connect directly to your virtual machine over the IP address in your `Homestead.yaml` file, then you can always connect over `3306`. In my case, my Homestead IP address is `192.168.10.10` and this allows me to define my `DB_PORT` as `3306` and have it work from wherever I run tests.

Your other alternative is to use a [Dusk environment file](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/dusk#environment-handling) to overide any environment variables specific to your Dusk tests - which would allow you to update the `DB_PORT` to `33060`.

Comment: Thanks, nice explanation. I'm now connecting over the IP address in `Homestead.yaml` and it works on the initial problem I had. Something else still standing in the way although not related. Algolia Search can't connect, that's stuff for another SO question :)